# Android, Kotlin. SpeechRecognizer is not working for some reason

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition

I'm working with android speech API called *SpeechRecognizer* trying to translate speech into text, but for some reason, as soon as I click on the button - I see the message **"CAN'T REACH GOOGLE AT THE MOMENT"**, and the window closes without waiting for my speech. Or the sound just stutters and nothing happens.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var voiceButton: Button? = null
    var textView: TextView? = null
    var listener: Listener? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initializeView()
        initializeListeners()
    }

    fun initializeView() {
        voiceButton = findViewById(R.id.voiceButton)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        listener = Listener()
    }
    fun initializeListeners() {
        voiceButton?.setOnClickListener {
            val speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
            speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener)
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);

            speechRecognizer.startListening(intent)

            if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 10)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unfortunately device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Just why? What's wrong with this code? I think this code should work because for other people it works fine. Maybe my emulator (**Nexus One API 22**) is not supported for this API? I just don't know what's the problem.

Maybe you do know how to solve it? Thanks, i'll be grateful for your help!

**IF SOMEBODY SUDDENLY FACES A SIMILAR PROBLEM, THAT'S HOW I SOLVE THIS PROBLEM AFTER A WHILE:**

You need to turn on **Virtual microphone uses host audio input**. Go to: More ("..." on the right side) -> Microphone -> Turn on "**Virtual microphone uses host audio input**".
Also, your emulator must have a later version of the update, otherwise speech recognition will not work.

Comment: Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: Well, no.What is the name of this permission? Thanks

Comment: You mean this one     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
?

Comment: Yes, that is the one.

Comment: it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think your listener is the problem, you cant just initialize `listener = Listener()`
and pass it to the speechRecognizer.It needs to receive a `RecognitionListener` type of listener which has many callbacks that you can use like `onResults` which indicates every time your listener catches voice speeched and more callbacks.
try changing your listener to `listener = object : RecognitionListener{ HERE OVERRIDE THE METHODS }` 
eventually it will looks like that:

```
     listener = object :RecognitionListener {
            override fun onReadyForSpeech(params: Bundle?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onRmsChanged(rmsdB: Float) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onBufferReceived(buffer: ByteArray?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onPartialResults(partialResults: Bundle?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onEvent(eventType: Int, params: Bundle?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onError(error: Int) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onResults(results: Bundle?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
```

you can read about any callback to make use of your own needs
hope it helps