# I'm not able to find speechRecognizer.startListening method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, speech-recognition

I'm learning android studio currently and making an application that converts audio to text,
in that I create one SpeechRecognizer object speechRecognizer but when I try to use startListening method it saw that there is no method like this

why it saw like that can anyone tell please

Comment: Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622244/android-kotlin-speechrecognizer-is-not-working-for-some-reason).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.